# Can I visualize a Multibody pose without explicitly calculating every body's full transform?

Tags: drake

In the `examples/quadrotor/` example, a custom `QuadrotorPlant` is specified and its output is passed into `QuadrotorGeometry` where the `QuadrotorPlant` state is packaged into `FramePoseVector` for the `SceneGraph` to visualize.

The relevant code segment in `QuadrotorGeometry` that does this:

```
...
  builder->Connect(
      quadrotor_geometry->get_output_port(0),
      scene_graph->get_source_pose_port(quadrotor_geometry->source_id_));
...

void QuadrotorGeometry::OutputGeometryPose(
    const systems::Context<double>& context,
    geometry::FramePoseVector<double>* poses) const {
  DRAKE_DEMAND(frame_id_.is_valid());

  const auto& state = get_input_port(0).Eval(context);
  math::RigidTransformd pose(
      math::RollPitchYawd(state.segment<3>(3)),
      state.head<3>());

  *poses = {{frame_id_, pose.GetAsIsometry3()}};
}
```

In my case, I have a floating based multibody system (think a quadrotor with a pendulum attached) of which I've created a custom plant (`LeafSystem`).  The minimal coordinates for such a system would be 4 (quaternion) + 3 (x,y,z) + 1 (joint angle) = 7.  If I were to follow the QuadrotorGeometry example, I believe I would need to specify the full `RigidTransformd` for the quadrotor and the full `RigidTransformd` of the pendulum.

### Question

Is it possible to set up the visualization / specify the pose such that I only need to specify the 7 (pose of quadrotor + joint angle) state minimal coordinates and have the internal `MultibodyPlant` handle the computation of each individual body's (quadrotor and pendulum) full `RigidTransform` which can then be passed to the `SceneGraph` for visualization?

I believe this was possible with the "attic-ed" (which I take to mean "to be deprecated") `RigidBodyTree`, which was accomplished in `examples/compass_gait`

```
  lcm::DrakeLcm lcm;
  auto publisher = builder.AddSystem<systems::DrakeVisualizer>(*tree, &lcm);
  publisher->set_name("publisher");

  builder.Connect(compass_gait->get_floating_base_state_output_port(),
                  publisher->get_input_port(0));
```

Where `get_floating_base_state_output_port()` was outputting the `CompassGait` state with only 7 states (3 rpy + 3 xyz + 1 hip angle).

What is the `MultibodyPlant`, `SceneGraph` equivalent of this?

#### Update (Using [MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1rendering_1_1_multibody_position_to_geometry_pose.html) from Russ's deleted answer

I created the following function which, attempts to create a `MultibodyPlant` from the given `model_file` and connects the given plant `pose_output_port` through `MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose`.

The `pose_output_port` I'm using is the 4(quaternion) + 3(xyz) + 1(joint angle) minimal state.

```
void add_plant_visuals(
        systems::DiagramBuilder<double>* builder,
        geometry::SceneGraph<double>* scene_graph,
        const std::string model_file,
        const systems::OutputPort<double>& pose_output_port)
{
    multibody::MultibodyPlant<double> mbp;
    multibody::Parser parser(&mbp, scene_graph);
    auto model_id = parser.AddModelFromFile(model_file);
    mbp.Finalize();

    auto source_id = *mbp.get_source_id();

    auto multibody_position_to_geometry_pose = builder->AddSystem<systems::rendering::MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose<double>>(mbp);
    builder->Connect(pose_output_port,
            multibody_position_to_geometry_pose->get_input_port());
    builder->Connect(
            multibody_position_to_geometry_pose->get_output_port(),
            scene_graph->get_source_pose_port(source_id));

    geometry::ConnectDrakeVisualizer(builder, *scene_graph);
}
```

The above fails with the following exception

```
abort: Failure at multibody/plant/multibody_plant.cc:2015 in get_geometry_poses_output_port(): condition 'geometry_source_is_registered()' failed.
```

Comment: Adding link provided by Russ in a previous answer whcih I thought was useful: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1rendering_1_1_multibody_position_to_geometry_pose.html

Comment: BTW I recognized that the doxygen for `MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose` had not rendered correctly -- the missing documentation called out the necessity of making sure the `MBP` stays alive. A PR is about to merge to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there's a lot in here. I have a suspicion there's a simple answer, but we may have to converge on it.

First, my assumptions:

1. You've got an "internal" MultibodyPlant (MBP). Presumably, you also have a context for it, allowing you to perform meaningful state-dependent calculations.
2. Furthermore, I presume the MBP was responsible for registering the geometry (probably happened when you parsed it).
3. Your `LeafSystem` will directly connect to the `SceneGraph` to provide poses.
4. Given your state, you routinely set the state in the MBP's context to do that evaluation.

### Option 1 (Edited):

In your custom `LeafSystem`, create the `FramePoseVector` output port, create the calc callback for it, and inside that callback, simply invoke the `Eval()` of the pose output port of the internal `MBP` that your `LeafSystem` own (having previously set the state in your locally owned `Context` for the `MBP` and passing in the pointer to the `FramePoseVector` that your `LeafSystem`'s callback was provided with).

Essentially (in a very coarse way):

```cpp
MySystem::MySystem() {
  this->DeclareAbstractOutputPort("geometry_pose",
      &MySystem::OutputGeometryPose);
}

void MySystem::OutputGeometryPose(
    const Context& context, FramePoseVector* poses) const {
  mbp_context_.get_mutable_continuous_state()
    .SetFromVector(my_state_vector);
  mbp_.get_geometry_poses_output_port().Eval(mpb_context_, poses);
}
```

### Option 2:

Rather than implementing a `LeafSystem` that has an internal plant, you could have a `Diagram` that contains an MBP and exports the MBP's `FramePoseVector` output directly through the diagram to connect.

Comment: Thx for the reply! I've updated my question based on the deleted reply by Russ (not sure why it was deleted).
Regarding your assumptions, my current set up is quite similar to the quadrotor example.  The MBP is only there for loading the model for visualizing.  All state-dependent calculations are done separate form that MBP in my custom LeafSystem.  I believe I'm stuck on 3 and 4 where I'm not exactly sure how I can connect the output of my LeafSystem to the SceneGraph to provide the pose.

Comment: I suppose the straightforward way would be to have my LeafSystem output each link (frame)'s pose via `*poses = {{frame_id_, pose.GetAsIsometry3()}}`.  However, I would like to avoid the unnecessary step of calculating each frame's pose and have the MBP do it for me.  I was wondering if I can simply specify the minimal coordinates (floating base + joint angle) and have MBP automatically find out the `poses`.

Comment: To clarify, my LeafSystem of which I implemented the dynamics of my plant does not contain a MultibodyPlant, similar to how the `QuadrotorPlant` does not contain an MBP.

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses, specifically, your edit where you are attempting to use the `MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose` approach. It doesn't address the larger design issues.

Your problem is that the `MultibodyPositiontToGeometryPose` system takes a reference to an `MBP` and keeps a reference to that same `MBP`. That means the `MBP` must be alive and well for at least as long as the `MPTGP` is. However, in your code snippet, your `MBP` is local to the `add_plant_visuals()` function so it is destroyed as soon as the function is over.

You'll need to create something that is persisted and owned by someone else.

(This is tightly related to my option 2 - now edited for improved clarity.)